# Sqlite Insert Runs Successfully But Does Have not any Effect On Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite

I am trying to add a single row to my table. It seems like it works just fine, but the row is not added to database. When i check the database there is no change on it.

I am trying to add it with insert method that SqliteDatabase provides with folowing code.

```java
public void saveToCache(String word) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("word", word);
    long value = database.insert("CACHE",null, contentValues);

    //The code below is for debug purposes, to see the if values are added
    //But when executed it gives 
    //android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, 
    //with a size of 13
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CACHE",null);
        for(int i=0; i< cursor.getCount();i++){
            String a = cursor.getString(0); //This is where the exception above happens

        }
}
```

The value attribute seems right, everytime I use the function, it increments by 1. But the rawQuery method below gives the error I have provided in the comment.

p.s : The table "CACHE" has only one COLUMN called word.

Comment: Invoke `cursor.moveToFirst()` before the loop to start fetching data.

Comment: Did you configure any autocommit attributes? It might be that the transaction is no committed.

Comment: @S-Sh thank you! I can see now the values are added to database. But weirdly, when i check it using the GUI, Sql Browser For Sqlite, I see no changes in the table.

Comment: @hmanolov I don't have any knowledge about autocommit attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the loop that accesses the rows returned to the cursor:

```
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CACHE",null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String a = cursor.getString(0); 
        // do something
    }
```

After the call to `rawQuery()` the cursor's index is before the 1st row (if it exists).
The cursor does not advance to the first or to the next row without a call to `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()`.